# Data from map isn't rendering in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs

I have successfully gathered data from an API and gathered it in a list, in my return statement the data isn't being rendered, in the console.log it logs fine, the data is there I just can't figure out why it isn't being put on the screen.

Class:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const PokemonRender = () => {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
  const tempPokemonArray = []
  const getPokemonData = async (id) => {
    try {
      fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + id).then(res => res.json()).then((pokemon) => tempPokemonArray.push(pokemon))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect((i) => {
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      getPokemonData(i)
    }
    setPokemonList(tempPokemonArray);
    tempPokemonArray.length = 0;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {pokemonList.map(poke=>(
          console.log(poke.name),
          <tr key={poke.id}>
            <td key={1}>{poke.id} Test</td>
            <td key={2}>{poke.name} Test 2</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </>
  )
};

export default PokemonRender;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to gather all the async results from the API and then set the state.

Tips: try not to mix `Promise.then().catch()` syntax with `async/await` within a single function. Pick one and stick with it. The `async/await` is probalby the best option due to its readability and sync-like syntax.

You might also consider adding a `isLoading` state that will render a "loading..." message or Component while the [API is fetching the results](https://blog.logrocket.com/ui-design-best-practices-loading-error-empty-state-react/).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const PokemonRender = () => {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
  const getPokemonData = async (id) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + id);
      const pokemon = await res.json();
      return pokemon;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect((i) => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      promises.push( getPokemonData(i) )
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((results)=>{
      setPokemonList(results);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {pokemonList.map(poke=>(
          <tr key={poke.id}>
            <td key={1}>{poke.id} Test</td>
            <td key={2}>{poke.name} Test 2</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </>
  )
};

export default PokemonRender;
```

---

*Live Snippet*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const PokemonRender = () => {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);

  const getPokemonData = async (id) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + id);
      const pokemon = await res.json();
      return pokemon;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect((i) => {
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      promises.push( getPokemonData(i) )
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((results)=>{
      setPokemonList(results);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {pokemonList.map(poke=>(
          <tr key={poke.id}>
            <td key={1}>{poke.id}</td>
            <td key={2}>{poke.name}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </>
  )
};
      ReactDOM.render(
        <PokemonRender />,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I'm still trying to wrap my head around asynchronous calls, what does promise.all do?

Comment: I've just added a link to the MDN documentation for Promise.all. Make sure to check it out.